# How do I install Intel C++ Compiler without admin privileges?

Tags: windows, installation, c++, intel

I was trying to install Intel C++ on my computer. I downloaded the offline installer for Windows (w_dpcpp-cpp-compiler_p_2023.0.0.25932_offline, 1.3 GB) from intel.com.

Then while trying to run the installer, admin privileges were required.

The problem is, I don't have admin rights on my PC and therefore I'm not able to install it.
I don't even know what is the need for administrator permission for installing a compiler.

I tried to find a way on the Internet but failed to get the required information.

Does anyone know how to install Intel C++ without admin rights in Windows?

Any reply is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Ask your admin.

Comment: If you can extract all the files (using 7zip or something else) to a location under your `%USERHOME%`  (or choose that as a destination) it is possible, but otherwise, no. Besides, there may be a company policy preventing you from installing non-sanctioned/unscanned/other unauthorized software, which means you will need to contact the admins/security dept. - It really sucks if the case is that you are hired as a  developer, and don't have the required tools. (some companies provied VMs or separate PCs for development to keep experiments isolated.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to verify company policy as regarding the installation of new
software. Your administrator might be able to help in installing
this compiler. If not, and if virtual machines are allowed, you could
use a VM where you are the administrator.

If you're just looking for any C++ compiler, see the article
[What are the best portable C++ compilers/IDEs?](https://www.slant.co/topics/1918/%7Ebest-portable-c-compilers-ides)

This article lists Code::Blocks, Geany portable, Orwell Dev-C++ and
Pocket C++. The first is pretty well-known.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you can extract all the files (using 7zip or some other extraction sofware) to a location under your `%USERHOME%` (or choose that as a destination before the the UAT prompt is displayed), then it is possible, but otherwise, **NO**.

Besides, there may be a company policy preventing you from installing non-sanctioned/unscanned/other unauthorized software, which means you will need to contact the admins/security dept.

It really sucks if the case is that you are hired as a  developer, and don't have the required tools. (some companies provide VMs or separate PCs for development to keep experiments isolated.) Make some enquiries to the people in charge of pcs or software acquiral.